# In a multithreaded program, are all threads blocked when one thread is doing heavy work inside the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, gil

As far as I understand, if I'm blocking for IO or calling an external library like what happens inside Numpy, then execution of other threads that need the Python interpreter can continue. However, if I'm - for example - doing heavy number crunching inside Python (without utilising Numpy), then that will block the Python interpreter which means all other threads doing similar work will be blocked.

Is that correct? And if so, is there a way to get around it?

Comment: The easiest way around the GIL is probably to use processes instead of threads. Unless you can't accept the overhead, but then I'd wonder if Python really is the right tool for that purpose.

Comment: Is that correct? Yes it is. And there are few workarounds if any because the GIL is a strong assumption in the Python interpretor. For heavy computation anyway, Python is not a very good tool alone, and you should considere Numpy and Scipy which have specific handling for the GIL, or Cython which allows almost natural inclusion of C code. BTW Numpy (and Scipy) are written using Cython.

Comment: thanks both, you answered my question.